# how to use this type key in json object?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am working on third parties apis get json object like this.

```
var data ={
"matches": [
{
  "unique_id": 1144995,
  "date": "2018-12-25T00:00:00.000Z",
  "dateTimeGMT": "2018-12-25T23:30:00.000Z",
  "team-1": "Australia",
  "team-2": "India",
  "type": "Test",
  "squad": true,
  "toss_winner_team": "India",
  "matchStarted": true
},
{
  "unique_id": 1153839,
  "date": "2018-12-25T00:00:00.000Z",
  "dateTimeGMT": "2018-12-25T22:00:00.000Z",
  "team-1": "New Zealand",
  "team-2": "Sri Lanka",
  "type": "Test",
  "squad": true,
  "toss_winner_team": "Sri Lanka",
  "matchStarted": true
},
],
 "type":"test"
}
```

But problem when use each looping data get key "team-1" and "team-2" value not get only "NaN" print option.

```
var container = $("#metch_container");
$.each(data.matches, function(key, value) {

                container.append($("<option></option>")
                .attr("value",value.unique_id)
                .text(value.team-1. +" VS " + value.team-2));
            });
```

Please sort out my problem thanks lot

Comment: Your JSON is invalid. At least it has a misplaced comma near the end

Comment: Main issue: `team_1. +" VS " + team_2` should be `value["team-1"] +" VS " + value.["team-2"]`

Comment: `.text(team_1. +" VS "`  typo with the period after `team_1`, though team_1 and team_2 are undefined.

Comment: After update there is now a comma too many.

Comment: Sorry Miss type main issue is like this .text(team-1. +" VS " + team-2)

Comment: `team-1` is not defined

Comment: @trincot you got a `value.[` typo at the end

Comment: Sorry Now edit my question like this "value.team-1. +" VS " + value.team-2"

Comment: Look at what trincot is doing.  You can't do `team-1`, because `-` is the subtraction operator. You have to use array notation with a string if you have non-standard variable names

Comment: @Taplar How to sort out this team-1, because - is the subtraction operator. Because of use third party apis.

Comment: "Look at what trincot is doing."

Answer (score 1):

Use `value["team-x"]` format if property name contain invalid characters:

```
var container = $("#metch_container");
$.each(data.matches, function(key, value) {

                container.append($("<option></option>")
                .attr("value",value.unique_id)
                .text(value["team-1"] +" VS " + value["team-2"]));
            });
```

I hope this will help you!

Comment: @Kheteshkumawat You can mark an answer accepted by clicking the pipe on it. This helps to others to find better answers to their similar questions.

Answer (score 1):

In this line:

```
.text(value.team-1. +" VS " + value.team-2));
```

You can't access values by `value.team-1` or `value.team-2`, as `team-2` refers to

> team minus 2

, not a recognized variable here:
What you can do here is:

```
.text(value["team-1"] +" VS " + value["team-2"]);
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all your JSON is invalid. Here is the valid JSON

Check [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/shoesheill/gjbzq7an/1/)

https://jsfiddle.net/shoesheill/gjbzq7an/1/

```js
var data = {
    "matches": [
    {
        "unique_id": 1144995,
        "date": "2018-12-25T00:00:00.000Z",
        "dateTimeGMT": "2018-12-25T23:30:00.000Z",
        "team-1": "Australia",
        "team-2": "India",
        "type": "Test",
        "squad": true,
        "toss_winner_team": "India",
        "matchStarted": true
    },
    {
        "unique_id": 1153839,
        "date": "2018-12-25T00:00:00.000Z",
        "dateTimeGMT": "2018-12-25T22:00:00.000Z",
        "team-1": "New Zealand",
        "team-2": "Sri Lanka",
        "type": "Test",
        "squad": true,
        "toss_winner_team": "Sri Lanka",
        "matchStarted": true
    }],
    "type": "test"
}
```

AND then If your key has `-` in it then use this

```
var container = $("#metch_container");

$.each(data.matches, function(key, value) {
container.append("<option>dvdfvfdv</option>")
     .attr("value",value.unique_id)
     .text(value['team-1'] +" VS " + value['team-2']);
   });
```

Comment: https://codebeautify.org/jsonvalidator/cb5d6187 validate your JSON here. You Have unnecessary comma `,` before  `],
"type":"test"
}`   @Kheteshkumawat

Comment: @Kheteshkumawat  try Validating your JSON and remember your _Downvote_